# Flask failed to load configuration from config.py

Tags: flask, config

My **__init__.py** file

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import app_config


db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

    db.init_app(app)

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return 'Hello, user'

    return app
```

I will find tutorial for flask 
[build crud app flask](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-crud-web-app-with-python-and-flask-part-one)

My **config.py** file:

```
import os

# Set path for our db
basedir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


class Config:
    DEBUG = True


class DevConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir,
                                                          'bookshell.db')
    SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = True
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False


class ProdConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False


class TestConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True


app_config = {
    'development': DevConfig,
    'production': ProdConfig,
    'testing': TestConfig
}
```

**run.py** file

```
import os

# Import from app/__init__
from app import create_app


config_name = os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG', 'development')
app = create_app(config_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

So, I tried to configure my own config.py file, but I get an error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] Unable to load configuration file (No such file or directory): '/Users/yevhensurzhenko/Desktop/Simple_login_form/instance/config.py'
```

But when I change some configuration, and when try to reload page it give me 
**405 error method not allowed
or**

```
app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
KeyError: <flask.cli.ScriptInfo object at 0x1038a5b70>
```

So, I made some changes, like

In **config.py** add

```
app_config = {
    ..
    'default': DevConfig
}
```

In **__init__.py** create instance dir.

```
from instance import config
```

And now I get output from func that I create in **__init__.py, in create__app()...**

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, user'
```

But, FLASK_CONFIG not change, it work only production, wtf:(

Comment: Why do you use both `from_object` and `from_pyfile` at the same time? Only `from_object` should do the job.

Comment: Also where do you set `FLASK_CONFIG` environment variable? I would recommend to set that variable in separate file with .env extensions. After that load it via `python-dotenv` library.

Comment: Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52164534/8916412

Comment: Open again __init__.py in /app dir, it's already commit 

`#app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')`

Thanks, for advise,