# Setting Flask configuration values doesn't seen to work

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to set `app.config['FLASK_ENV'] = 'development'` but when I run the app it starts runs with default configs (production environment).

My code is as simple as possible:

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['FLASK_ENV'] = 'development'

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

I'm kind of frustrated with Flask at this point as growing from a single file app example to a more structured small app is not covered in documentation. Every single example I found goes from hello world to a full large app, which makes the learning kind of a pain.

Comment: You might get some guidance from the Flask Mega Tutorial (https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world"), which walks you through building a less-than-trivial app, starting from the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're setting configurations correctly, but from the Flask [configuation docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/), you won't be able to set the environment in the code.

> The ENV and DEBUG config values are special because they may behave
>   inconsistently if changed after the app has begun setting up. In order
>   to set the environment and debug mode reliably, Flask uses environment
>   variables.

You can run development mode by calling the following:

```
$ export FLASK_ENV=development
$ flask run
```

Or, the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52164534/5050285) has other alternatives to set environment variables for your flask application.

Comment: The actual issue is that OP sets `app.config['FLASK_ENV']` instead of `app.config['ENV']`. The part of the documentation that you quote does not apply to OP's example, because setup of an application refers to what happens on the first HTTP request.