# Flask environment not changing to development

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables

Whenever running my `Flask` app on `VSCode` I am unable to change the environment to development. I have searched relevant links on this topic and tried all the solutions and combinations of solutions, nothing so far has worked. I would like my app to refresh whenever I make a change in either any of the template files or my app.py file. Here is a list of what I've tried:

1. Typing in `"set FLASK_ENV=development"` on my terminal from [this stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344756/auto-reloading-python-flask-app-upon-code-changes) I am on Windows, so I instead used set
2. Pip installing `python-dotenv` and creating a `.env` or `.flaskenv.` file inside my root directory (yes I tried both) then adding `FLASK_ENV=development` as well as `set FLASK_ENV=development` inside both files (at different times trying all combinations) like [this stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162882/set-flask-environment-to-development-mode-as-default) mentioned
3. Editing my main flask app file with the lines mentioned in the solution from list item number two...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

4. Yes I have read the documentation for `python-dotenv` [here](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) and added `load_dotenv()` after my import statements

See here start of my app.py code:

```
"""This is my controller"""

import re

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session
from cs50 import SQL
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()


from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 

# turn the current file into a web application that will listen for browsers requests
# __name__ refers to the current file
app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And as you can see `Environment: production` still shows from terminal window

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With powershell the syntax for env vars is different. To change the `FLASK_ENV` variable, type:

```
$env:FLASK_ENV = "development"
```

You can verify it with `gci env:` command that list all of the env vars. After that the `flask run` will run in development mode.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that for some reason Flask uses `ENV` variable instead of `FLASK_ENV`.

Try setting `ENV=development` in your `.env` file, it worked for me.