# Synology webstation simple "hello world" quick start with python, flask and uwsgi

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, synology

I noticed that Synology's native webstation which uses uwsgi framework, has recently added support for python script. I was wondering if someone can help me figure out a simple hello world example. I am unclear about what to put in the uwsgi file.
I followed the python-flask quickstart example on uwsgi documentation page:
[uwsgi python-flask quickstart](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#deploying-flask)

On webstaion>service portal : I setup a virtual host with nginx listening on port 8080:
[image: webstation virtual host profile]

In this profile I then setup the appropriate folder containing the python script, callable entry function and uwsgi file:
[image]

The "main.py" python script residing in this folder is the example in the quickstart page:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "<span style='color:red'>I am app 1</span>"
```

I took the command-line parameters in that example and made the uwsgi.ini file and placed it in the same folder:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:8080
wsgi-file = main.py 
callable = app 
processes = 4
threads = 2 
stats = 127.0.0.1:9191
```

In webstation's script>python page : I setup a "python-flask profile" and added the required flask module:
[image]

[image]

I added this "python-flask profile" in the virtual host's python profile to make sure all modules are accessible to the python script.

However, when I browse to port 8080 I get error code 500 on my browser;

```
Internal Server Error
```

[image]

I would greatly appreciate if someone could try this out on webstation to figure out the correct setup. It seems that webstation makes deploying python based web-apps quite easy so solving this issue would greatly benefit newbies like me who are looking for a quick and easy deployment method on their Synology NAS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was also on this chase.... and find https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/153851 where this question is also posted.... did you find a way ?

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you should pick your `*.py` file in this field

[image: Field]

Comment: This solution worked for me : If your flask app is called "testapp.py" then enter "testapp.py" in the "WSGI file" field.

Answer (score 5):

I do not have the full answer, but I was able to make it work.
Here is my setup.

At the **Web Station** application:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

At my **router**:
[image]

What I can see on my **web browser**.
Tested with and without VPN (to simulate being outside my local network).
Works with HTTP and HTTPS.
[image]

My **Python** code at *main.py* (same as OP) is:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "<span style='color:green'>I am app 1</span>"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

A few limitations:

- I am not able to make it work with another port. For example, 8080
- The "Hostname" must be set
- Only work with ports 80/443
- Clear your browser cache
- I am not able to find the server log
- If the code crashes, it needs to *Disable* and *Enable* the Virtual Host

Comment: I was looking for flask and synology and this totaly helped me out whit the installation process..... i got 1 question... do you know how to set the flask in debug mode ? $ export FLASK_ENV=development

Comment: @hexedecimal, I haven't tried. I would try to login to the NAS using SSH. Then, using an `administrator` account, try to set the environment variable. Maybe you need to `sudo` the command.

Comment: @hexedecimal, alternatively, you could try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python. Or my current personal preference, use a **Docker** with Python installed.

Comment: do you mean the python-dotenv answer in the link?
via ssh i don't know how to set this export at all... or how to connect to the loaded python to set the development... 
I'm a little bit noobish around this and thinking about this wrong... was glad whit this step by step screenshots :).... a docker option --> i dont know how to connect this via the webserver... again was glad i got this working :D

Comment: @hexedecimal, did you try: ```import os
os.environ["FLASK_ENV"] = "development"```? Maybe it is the easiest way to make it work. 
Other option, usgin ```if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)``` (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52164534/3780957).

Comment: You can also set configuration parameters, using a `.cfg` file. Check: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/

Answer (score 2):

## Server logs

I found that (running DSM 7.1 and Python 3.9) Python errors on my machine appear in

python3.9-uwsgi.log

in

/volume1/@appdata/Python3.9/logs

Answer (score 0):

For flask, I had to start on 0.0.0.0 to ensure the app was accessible from the LAN/WAN. If started on 127.0.0.1 or localhost, only the computer itself could access the app. It may be a first hint, for you?
I manage to made my app run and accessible from the web but I still have to start it manually (ssh > command line) so it closed every time I closed the synology user session. On this part you seems far ahead of me.

Comment: Could you provide more feedback on what do you mean about port addresses 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1? Where those addresses should be set?

Comment: @juanbretti here are to command line that explain the 0.0.0.0 starting point :
uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:xxxx --master --wsgi-file run.py --callable app --threads 2
flask run -h 0.0.0.0 -p portNb
When I started with those commands, the server was accessible on my local IP and on localhost. It was not otherwise. Only local IP or only localhost/127.0.0.1 .

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z2eS.png)

as already pointed out from @Jeremie you have to enter here (or navigate with "Browse...") to your "main.py"
! Ensure, that you have seted up the Root-Path corectly and the "main.py" is exactly at that location!

@ juanbretti: I get it also run without "Hostname"-Config so with only use a HTTP-Port and the same Hostname/IP as SynologyNAS

BR

Comment: update: and delete any "app.run()" statement in main.py will help

Momently I not figured out how to run in debug mode....

Comment: I haven't tried without "hostname" defined. Thank you @user19329672 for letting me know.