# Configure Syslog on a python flask app deployed on a Synology server

Tags: python, flask, synology

I have successfully (or had) deployed a flask app on my synology server following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72597109/synology-webstation-simple-hello-world-quick-start-with-python-flask-and-uwsg).

It works, but from time to time, like now, I can run my app locally but it fails when I run it on the synology. My issue is that I have not figured out how to configure the error page on the synology, so I  just get the  "Internal Server Error" and I cant see what is failing.

I found [this guide](https://medium.com/@rizqinur2010/deploying-python-flask-in-synology-dsm-7-without-docker-d99f1603bc87), and I tried to send the errors to syslog, but not even the manual test work for me (step2 and 3 of syslog in the blog).

Anyone has this figured out?

my app structure is:

```
foldername
    run.py
    myappFolder
       __init__.py
       staticFolder
       functionsFolder
       .....
```